# Adding buttons and controls on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, three.js

I'm using the three.js 3D engine. How can I add UI buttons on my WebGL canvas?

Comment: What are the down and close votes for? It's a legitimate question, I think. If not, humor me with a reason. Note, however, the OP should provide a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net) and code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to absolute positioning HTML elements over `<canvas>`.

`<canvas>` is just like all other HTML elements and the same tricks work on it.

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: @CoryGross I saw your demo. I want to create UI on my webgl canvas like your option button. can you recommand for me some references about UI??