# Text editing controls in HTML5 <canvas>

Tags: html5-canvas

I have found that many of them are suggesting to avoid canvas tag to implement text editing option in html5. But I could not found the alternative option for this "Authors should avoid implementing text editing controls using the canvas element.". Can anyone tell me the alternative solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use parent relative positioning with `<canvas>` and place your HTML UI logic over the top of the canvas.

Example:

[Adding buttons and controls on HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343053/adding-buttons-and-controls-on-html5-canvas/12343088#12343088)

It's not alternative solution per se, but the only sane way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Mikko :) I am doing a POC for creating a Notebook in HTML5. Its features are: 1. Able to type text across the notebook.
2. Draw a figure on notebook and on the text.
3. Able to use audio/video files. Is it possible to do it using a canvas element?

Comment: Thanks. pls provide any inputs for my notebook POC

Comment: I have tried this way, but still i'm facing problem like not able to edit the text. i need to create textarea like editable content in canvas. can u tell me any other way to do the same.

Comment: Please demostrate your problem by creating an isolated test case with jsfiddle.net service how it is not working for you. It is difficult to help you if you don't demostrate what you have tried and how it is failing.